# plugin:vite:import-analysis: Failed to resolve import "../../views/main/index" from "src/router/module/mobile-routes.js". Does the file exist?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, error-handling

In my Vue JS application, I have the following js inside src/router
index.js

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'
import { isMobileTerminal } from '../utils/flexible'
import mobileRoutes from './module/mobile-routes'
import pcRoutes from './module/pc-routes'

// 创建 vueRouter实例
const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(),
  routes: isMobileTerminal.value ? mobileRoutes : pcRoutes
})

export default router
```

And I have the following mobile-routes.js inside src/router/module

```
export default [
  {
    path: '/', // 路径
    name: 'home', // 当前路由名字
    component: () => import('../../views/main/index') // 对应的组件
  }
]
```

Then I have a component called, index.vue inside src/views/main

```
<template>
  <div>
    移动端首页
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
export default {
  name: 'index'
}
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped></style>
```

Every time I tried to run my application, it kept giving me the following errors:
**[plugin:vite:import-analysis] Failed to resolve import "../../views/main/index" from "src/router/module/mobile-routes.js". Does the file exist?**

ERROR as shown in the figure
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KoSGH.png)

I'm using tailwind CSS ，vite and Vue 3

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by vite,need to add a suffix, that is .vue in vite.
Alter mobile-routes.js inside src/router/module

```
export default [
  {
    path: '/', // 路径
    name: 'home', // 当前路由名字
    component: () => import('../../views/main/index.vue') // 对应的组件
  }
]
```

**I find the right answer at this website**[enter link description here](https://www.csdn.net/tags/NtTaggwsMTQ0MTQtYmxvZwO0O0OO0O0O.html)